# Installing a second dual channel memory set next to an existing one

Tags: memory, motherboard, upgrade

I currently have a system with an [Asus Maximus Formula](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/Maximus_Formula/#specifications) motherboard and 2GB RAM (dual-channel DDR2). I'm considering upgrading to 4GB RAM, but i wouldn't like to buy 4GB since i think DDR2 is over-priced (DDR3 is much cheaper, but my card doesn't support it).

**I'm considering buying another 2GB dual-channel set and adding it. Are there any issues i should consider?**

I'm thinking of:

- does the new set need of RAM need to be the same frequency as the old one? (i guess the answer would be yes)
- does the vendor count (i think it shouldn't).

Any other tips are welcome.

Comment: Asus seems to have a compatability list for download.  have you checked that?  http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/Maximus_Formula/#MSL

Comment: I had a look. But i'm not sure how to read it? Does the "V" means a certain stick will work in that DIMM slot? And missing the "V" that it doesn't? 
Also, i think the QVL is not an exhaustive list of what will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not had any issues mixing vendors or frequencies on Asus motherboards; that being said, is no guarantee since I've not used the Maximus Formula model specifically. The motherboard simply runs everything at the lowest common denominator (i.e., the fastest speed that *both* memory chips support).

Comment: +1 well said, most mobos do run at the lowest common denominator, faster memory will be clocked down to match.  You will never have memory running at different timings.

Comment: Well, i guess i should be safe adding a new dual-channel pair then. I'll check the model i have when i get home, but i doubt i can find exactly the same. I guess same frequency will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can always mix and match memory, however the rule of thumb is this, make sure they are both of course DDR2 (as you point out, its expensive, and you can't just add DDR3) and that if your board support DUAL CHANNEL (increase in performance) you want a **matched pair**. Otherwise you won't run ing *dual channel*.

Nothing short of a compatibility list should stop you from adding any memory you want, it will always 'dumb' down faster memory to match the slowest (keep that in mind like @DarthAndroid said).